# Dota 2 crashes after hitting play game. Sometimes on load screen and sometimes after hero selection

Tags: 14.04, games, steam, opengl

I performed every "help" given in the forums. I had previously upgraded to 14.10 which was when these problems started. I re-installed back to 14.04 but no luck with the steam or dota 2.

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20141111165118)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1415724678)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20141111165118)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1415724678)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1415724678)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[1115/134719:ERROR:nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
FillInMachineIDInfo took a total of 0 milliseconds
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49,15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311,30 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
local (potentially out of sync) copy of roaming config loaded - 1005 bytes.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Adding licenses for the following package(s): 0, 13054, 16515, 30403, 54611, 54613
roaming config store loaded successfully - 1005 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Failed to init SteamVR because it isn't installed
ExecCommandLine: ""/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam" "
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
System startup time: 11,68 seconds
Generating new string page texture 68: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442,37 KB
Generating new string page texture 69: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131,07 KB
Generating new string page texture 70: 384x256, total string texture memory is 835,58 KB
Generating new string page texture 71: 64x256, total string texture memory is 901,12 KB
Generating new string page texture 72: 32x256, total string texture memory is 933,89 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
[1115/134726:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
ExecCommandLine: "/home/ggvisor/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Generating new string page texture 88: 256x256, total string texture memory is 393,22 KB
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[1115/134730:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
Generating new string page texture 96: 384x256, total string texture memory is 786,43 KB
Generating new string page texture 97: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1,06 MB
Generating new string page texture 123: 24x256, total string texture memory is 1,09 MB
Game update: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 2605, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 2608 != 2607, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(20141111165126)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(gameoverlayui)/version(1.0)
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 570
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198008936291 [API loaded yes]
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Setting Steam ID:  76561198008936291
SDL video target is 'x11'
SDL failed to create GL compatibility profile (whichProfile=0!
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_fence.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_fence.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_sync.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_draw_buffers2.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_bindable_uniform.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_flush_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_map_buffer_range.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_occlusion_query.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_texture_range.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_APPLE_client_storage.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_framebuffer_object.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_GREMEDY_string_marker.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ARB_debug_output.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_direct_state_access.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NV_bindless_texture.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_AMD_pinned_memory.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GL_ATI_meminfo.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3.
This system supports the OpenGL extension GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5.
This system DOES NOT support the OpenGL extension GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear.
GL_NV_bindless_texture: DISABLED
GL_AMD_pinned_memory: DISABLED
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode: AVAILABLE
GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info: UNAVAILABLE
GL_ATI_meminfo: UNAVAILABLE
GL_MAX_SAMPLES_EXT: 8
Adding VPK file: /home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/dota/sound_vo_english
Adding VPK file: /home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/dota/pak01
Adding VPK file: /home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/platform/pak01
Did not detect any valid joysticks.
WARNING: unable to link Test_StartScript and Test_StartScript because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link Test_RandomChance and Test_RandomChance because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link Test_LoopForNumSeconds and Test_LoopForNumSeconds because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link Test_Loop and Test_Loop because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link Test_LoopCount and Test_LoopCount because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link Test_StartLoop and Test_StartLoop because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link log_flags and log_flags because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link log_color and log_color because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link log_verbosity and log_verbosity because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link log_level and log_level because one or more is a ConCommand.
WARNING: unable to link log_dumpchannels and log_dumpchannels because one or more is a ConCommand.
Load a scaleform font provider?
Creating D3D9 device with D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED
IDirect3DDevice9::Create: BackBufWidth: 1366, BackBufHeight: 768, D3DFMT: 3, BackBufCount: 1, MultisampleType: 0, MultisampleQuality: 0
GL sampler object usage: DISABLED

 ##### swap interval = 1     swap limit = 1 #####
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
!! Controller config file passed by steamworks game 570 did not exist at /home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/dota/cfg/controller.vdf
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1415758987)
[1115/134827:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
[1115/134828:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20141111165118)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1415724678)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(dota_linux)/version(1.0)
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198008936291 [API loaded yes]
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Setting Steam ID:  76561198008936291
[1115/134910:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(227)] Running without renderer sandbox
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20141115134753_1.dmp
/home/ggvisor/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/dota 2 beta/dota.sh: line 77:  2610 Bus error               (core dumped) ${GAME_DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
Game removed: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 2610 

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.

(steam:2437): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Trying to remove a child that doesn't believe we're it's parent.
Generating new string page texture 246: 128x256, total string texture memory is 1,22 MB
Requested Force create but SharedObjectMutex already created
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
Forced create but already created for SharedObjectEvent
[2014-11-15 13:47:11] Startup - updater built Nov 11 2014 16:51:13
[2014-11-15 13:47:12] Verifying installation...
[2014-11-15 13:47:12] Verification complete
[2014-11-15 13:51:15] Shutdown
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: Couldn't connect to server
pid 2685 != 2684, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got exactly the same problem (sometimes it crashed in a library, sometimes after hitting 'play') but this helped:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

after that, I can just run Steam by

```
primusrun steam
```

and everything works fine without errors.